# Label property assignment (dot v method)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development,I was working with a `UILabel`. I found that the `label` properties are set in multiple different ways.

In the below code, it can be seen that `text` is assigned using the bracket notation, while
`textColor` is assigned using dot notation. This has confused me...

```
[lblview setText:Cname];
lblview.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lblview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:18];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either.

```
lblview.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

is equivalent to

```
[lblview setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

The dot separator is just shorthand for getting/setting properties, instead of having to invoke the appropriate setter/getter method.

Comment: So can i say  lblview.setText=@"Hello" instead of [lblview setText:Cname]

Comment: no. The syntax is to either use a method call with setProperty, or dot notation without the word set, like lblview.text=@"Hello". Note that with the method call, you capitalize the first letter of the property name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both method for setting some value

```
[lblview setText:Cname];

lblview.setText = Cname;
```

specially set property by .(dot) method, when you made property in .h class